# Check if 'pdo->query foreach' return null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

The database is fine but i can't figure why $ROW cannot be recognized as NULL.

I have this code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->hostname . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname, $this->username, $this->password);

foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM people WHERE name="Joshua"') as $row):
    if($row['name'] != NULL):
        echo "WE HAVE ONE JOSHUA";
    else:
        echo "WE DO NOT HAVE ANY JOSHUA";
    endif;
endforeach;
```

When i run this script i got the: "WE HAVE ONE JOSHUA" message;

When i change name="Joshua" in PDO->QUERY for a name that does not exist on database i do not receive the "WE DO NOT HAVE ANY JOSHUA" message;

Any hints to deal with this?

I just want to create a statement that control if the FOREACH return NULL or NOT.

Thanks in advance and sry the bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
foreach($pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) totalCOunt FROM people WHERE name="Joshua"') as $row):
    if($row['totalCOunt'] != 0):
        echo "WE HAVE ONE JOSHUA";
    else:
        echo "WE DO NOT HAVE ANY JOSHUA";
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: why do you need to iterate?

Comment: The code i put in here is a example of what i really need. Actually i need to check if user LOGIN and PASSWORD match with in database information.

Comment: @Alexandre you don't need to iterate for this either

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you give-me a example? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can test if the result is null using the PDO rowCount. See:

```
$cmd = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM people WHERE name="Joshua"');
$cmd->execute();
if ($cmd->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while ($row = $cmd->fetch())
    {
        do...
    }
}
```

PDO not return errors. You can use the PDOStatement::errorCode().

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop only to deal with multiple rows
While if you're getting only one row, no loops required.

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM people WHERE name="Joshua"');
$row = $result->fetch();
if ($row) {
   echo "WE HAVE ONE JOSHUA";
   // here you have Joshua's data in $row
} else {
    echo "WE DO NOT HAVE ANY JOSHUA";
}
```